# I want to add extra lines to my ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I constructed this figure and with the following R code

[image]

```
 ggplot(data = sc, aes(x = x, y = y))
+ geom_polygon(aes(fill = fill)) 
+ geom_point(data = leeu, aes(x = x, y = y)) 
+ coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1000, 1000), ylim = c(-100, 1200))
```

but I would like to add black lines as in the picture below.

[image]

The lines start at center of circle and pass through each black point. How can I construct the lines?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to define a new geom, have a look at these instructions: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html